# distinctUntilChanged with ngrx

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I'm struggling with the code sample below. I've tried having `compareFilters` always `return true`, and always `return false`, and either way I am getting lots of "*******" in my logs - at least one should have completely cut off supply I expected? What am I missing?

```
    this.filters = this.store
        .select(state => state.filters)
        // This line needed as otherwise change in geolocation triggers state to be
        // resent, overwriting any changes user has made on filters menu
        .pipe(
            distinctUntilChanged(compareFilters),
            tap((filters: Filters) => {
                console.log("*****", filters);
                this.location.pushState(
                    {},
                    "",
                    "/recommendations/" + toUrl(filters)
                );                    
            })
        );
```

More generally, what I see in my components is that no matter which part of the state has changed `ngOnChanges` reports changes in all props every time

Comment: I like your approach, in fact I tried exactly the same thing and got the same disappointing result - e.g. when return true always / when return false always ... it still allows everything to do down the pipe

Comment: ah I worked out my issue - I am using angular and there are 25 instances of the component and each one is subscribing separately - so it looks like the pipe is being fired 25 times, but in fact its being fired once for each instance

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I don't think so. I wrote the quick example on StackBliz and it work as expected. Only 1 is printed. Are you sure that the ngrx store does not emit all thous events? Because your rxjs code is correct.

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged, tap  } from 'rxjs/operators';

of("1", "2", "3", "4" ,"5")
.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(coperator),
  tap(t => console.log(t))
)
.subscribe()

function coperator(t){
  return true;
}
```

May be the problem is with the call to `this.location.pushState` you call in your tap method something that modifies your store so that generate a new event. I don't know but it wont hurt to bounce some ideas.

Comment: thanks for the ideas - so far none of them have solved my issues, but I'm going to start commenting out things and try to work out what is happening